# Unexpected Error with no Correlation ID

Tags: 2010, upgrade, browsers

I have just created a new SharePoint 2010 farm. The topology is a single WFE with a separate SQL server back end. Both servers are utilising Windows Server 2012 R2.

I attached a backup of one of our production SP2007 environment content databases to the web application and ran an in-place upgrade. When the process was complete I made myself a Site collection administrator for the root site collection through Central Admin and attempted to access the site.

[image: Error Message]

This is not a helpful error message. I've checked the Event Logs and ULS and can't find anything with a reference to this URL, affecting the right subsystem taking place at remotely the right time.

Can anyone tell me what might have caused this?